# .htaccess redirect doesn't work for me

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have ubuntu server with apache. Everythink works fine. Now I have 8 domains. One is linked with virtualhost. Let's call it maindomain.com. Other 7 domains are linked to another virtualhost, let's call it secondarydomain1.com to secondarydomain7.com.

I need these 7 domains to be redirected to main domain. Everything after / must be redirected to base domain. For example secondarydomain2.com/file.php will be redirected to maindomain.com

Can someone help me how to do it with .htaccess file?

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^secondarydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://maindomain.com [R=301,L]
```

The result is "You don't have permission to access /file.php on this server."

Comment: Does the VirtualHost config (or `<Directory>` within it) have a `AllowOverride` directive? Without it, no .htaccess file will be parsed at all.

Comment: Yes, I have AllowOverride all between <Directory> tags

Comment: And it works, because it redirects me if I use only a domain name, but if there is something after slash, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable rewrites in apache.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Your rule isn't adding the request uri back to the domain part, which is why you aren't getting a redirection for the subparts as you expect.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^secondarydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://maindomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Tested on a test box:

```
curl http://192.168.163.161/test.html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://maindomain.com/test.html">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at 192.168.163.161 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Comment: This is enabled, there is another site that use mod rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

I have some news. In fact, working redirects didn't really work. They were caused by Chrome cache. After cleaning cache, I get error "You don't have permission to access /info.php on this server." if .htaccess looks only like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Btw. I can see mod_rewrite enabled in phpinfo.